# How to wire occupancy sensor with dimmer

Tags: wiring, bathroom, dimmer-switch

I am remodeling bathroom. The code now requires occupancy switch on all lights there but I also need to have a dimmer on main lights (LED). What is the simplest way to combine those two?
I can't find any good dimmer with occupancy sensor. Is there any product like that?

Comment: I believe the code specifies this only for commercial.  But that was only a quick reading

Comment: @ChrisCudmore It may be a local code.

Comment: I agree with Chris commercial and residential are different.

Comment: I also agree with @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  There may be local regulations at play here.  The point is that Asker  should double check the requirement.

Comment: It's California code. After additional research it appears that only one  light needs to be controlled by an  occupancy sensor. So I will just put vanity light on it and dimmer on main light as suggested in the answer.

Comment: I believe Code allows efficient lighting *instead of* an occupancy sensor.   "Efficient lighting" means fixtures which are inherently efficient and cannot be made non-efficient by someone screwing incandescent bulbs.  I.e. they must be made to not accept incandescent bulb bases.

Comment: simply chain each one series, which forms a logical AND. You could also wire them in parallel, a logical OR, in which case it would go from dim to bright when occupied.

Comment: What sort of lighting are you using? Conventional fixtures with screw-in bulbs? Fluorescents? Integrated LED fixtures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to go to a double box, or get some expensive speciality item. Since you are remodeling adding the box should not be a big deal. If that sensor is required add a small accent light, use the shower light or the other lights with the sensor and the dimmer as normal on your main lights. If you like, not recommended, you should be able to have the sensor power the dimmer but this could be tricky depending on what products you use.